# Should I differentiate bad login and bad password error codes?

Tags: security

I am designing a basic website which access is restricted by a classic login & password system.

I can't decide whether I should show a different message when the user enters a non-existing login, and when he enters an invalid password for an existing account.

My first intuition would be not to show a different message, because that would give hints to potential attackers about what is wrong but doing so would sometimes makes more difficult for the user to understand his errors (perhaps he just mistyped his account login and an appropriate error message would be better). On another hand, I often heard that the account login was not a **secret** (as the **password** obivously is) and so giving information about it should not lower the security level.

Do you guys have any good practice/rationale that I should follow regarding this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't differentiate these - it is information that can be used by malicious parties.

If they know a username is right, they already have valuable information that you have leaked.

It is a minor inconvenience to your users why exactly the login failed, they still have to enter both username and password, after all.

Comment: Also, if there is a "forgot password?" box where you type an email address to reset the password (and let's hope it is a reset and not emailing the original password back), you always say that an email has been sent, even if the email address isn't registered. Telling the user that the email address isn't registered allows them to keep trying different email addresses until they get a hit.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between "message" and "error code".

When a user unsuccessfully attempts to login, it's probably a good idea to differentiate **internally** between bad username and bad password (perhaps for logging purposes).

However, the **message** that's displayed to the user should be the same in both case- something like "you have provided an incorrect username/password *combination*".  If you use different messages in each case, you''re essentially providing a "does this username exist?" form, which can help would-be-attackers gain access to user accounts.

Using the same messages may indeed cause a small inconvenience to users, but ultimately security should be a higher priority.  In any case, it's now more-or-less common practice to display the same message for both bad username and bad password.

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to behave the same in borh cases, so as not to help an attacker find out which user names are valid. If he already dies, no harm done, and if he doesn't, don't make it easier for him. This is one of the scenarios where the inconvenience to legit users is thought to be less important than the defenses against malevolent third parties.

Answer (score 0):

I argue that there isn't any specific reason to not tell the user whats wrong. the question has been asked before and you can see my answer here (but please forgive my bad English): https://stackoverflow.com/a/8612838/455006

But the highlights are these:
The system should be made so that brute-forcing is as hard as possible, even if the attacker knows a username and you should more or less count on the fact that "they" know at least one username since there are a number of ways to guess or calculate those with quite some accuracy. To rely on the attacker not knowing the username is bordering to security by obscurity which is bad, and also if you always count on an attacker knowing the usernames your security schemes and plans will most probably be much better.

Please note that there are some cases where these arguments aren't so relevant: These are cases where the username in it self can be used for malicious activities (ie. The username is an email address which can be used to send spam, or some account-number which can be used for phishing attacks and so on). You could argue that the content on the site could be so important that even the protection by obscurity is important, but in that case it is my firm belief that you should use 2-factor authentication, single-use passwords or something similar instead. There are a number of open-source and/or free solutions for this.